# How to create an instance of a string VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, string, ftp, instance

Okay, I'm making this program that automatically gets the username and password from my remote  ftp server, and logs in. But it's giving me an error that says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Here is a sample of my code:

```
    Imports System.Net
    Imports System.Net.FtpClient
    Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Using ftp = New FtpClient()
        Dim credentials As New NetworkCredential
        ftp.Host = "my ftp server"
        credentials = ftp.Credentials
        Dim username As String
        username = credentials.UserName.ToString 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object
        Dim password As String
        password = credentials.Password.ToString
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: What does `credentials` contain in its properties? Is `credentials.UserName = Nothing`? If so, that's why you're getting your error.

Comment: I may sound like a noob, but wouldn't the "credentials = ftp.credentials" line give it the username and password?

Comment: @user2221877 No - FtpClient doesn't have a username or password until you set it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your problem is here:

```
' credentials = ftp.Credentials
' Should be:
ftp.Credentials = credentials
```

Once you've set this, you need to put in the credentials, not fetch them:

```
Dim username As String = GetUserNameFromSomewhere()
credentials.UserName = username
' Same as password
```

Right now, you're creating a `NetworkCredential`, then "throwing it away" and replacing it from the `FtpClient` credentials.  Since you haven't set them up, these are `Nothing`, which in turn leads to the exception when you try to fetch the `UserName`.

Answer (score 0):

With the `NetworkCredential` your supposed to set them not retrieve them from this object. These credentials are passed to the FtpClient. So without being set they are `Nothing` and hence the error.